# JSOUP: Getting a td with a specific rowspan

Tags: java, jquery

I've just recently picked up Jsoup to aid me in a personal project of mine. Right now i'm trying to parse specific data from this table but i'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that. Basically i'm trying to extract the text from the td with rowspan="2" but I can't seem to figure out the right select statement to use. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```html
<table style="background-color:inherit;line-height:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="font-size:16px;width:30px;">16</td>
      <td style="padding:0px;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;"><span style="color:#ff0000;">11</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0px;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;"><span style="color:#0000ff;">5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector like following.

```js
alert( $('td[rowspan="2"]').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="background-color:inherit;line-height:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="font-size:16px;width:30px;">16</td>
      <td style="padding:0px;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;"><span style="color:#ff0000;">11</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0px;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;"><span style="color:#0000ff;">5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
Elements rowspans = doc.select("td[rowspan=2]");
String text = rowspans.text();
```

Result will be a single string. But if you have multiple rowspan=2's, it might be better to store the data as elements in an array:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element rowspan : rowspans) {
    array.add(rowspan.text());
}
```